# What is the correct provider definition for MySQL with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

What is the most up to date setup for the provider for use with MySQL and Entity Framework 6?

I was using the following, but I've noticed that MySQL have pulled `MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6` from Nuget so I assume it's no longer valid.

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
```

It was working fine, but now I don't know where to get version 6.9.6.0 of the DLL from.

Every example that I look at and also MySQL's own getting started guide still mentions `MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6` - it's bizarre

Comment: Do you get any error? Or you are not able to get the package from Nuget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for the site from which you can download the EF6 connector DLL's then the below URL is what you are after

[Download Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Also [This post might come handy any time](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264)